# How to make a join from tables of multiple databases?

Tags: android, join

I have a read-only table in a SQLite DB file and a dynamically created table in another SQLite DB. I would like to make is a join of these two. The problem I see is that a query gets executed on one SQLiteDatabase object, so any columns from other databases are not known(e.g. FROM entries, DB2.entries). What I would like to have is something like this:

```
SELECT e1.id
FROM DB1.entries AS e1, DB2.entries AS e2
WHERE e1.id = e2.id
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html), it should be possible by attaching the second database to the same connection:

ATTACH /file/database2.db AS DB2;

Comment: Thanks, that was the pointer I needed. Since I'm working on Android, the attaching is done like this: `db.execSQL("attach database ? as aka_db", new String[]{ context.getDatabasePath("my_db").getPath() });`